# Confusion about local branch having updates from parent branch after git pull

Tags: git, branch, checkout, pull

(I am relatively new to git, so please excuse any obvious mistakes or questions) How does checking out a secondary branch show changes made to the parent branch that were added *after* the secondary branch branched off the parent?

For context, let's say branch A branched off master. Now, I make another branch off of A, called B. After B was created, some changes were pushed to A. B does not have these changes. I have branch A checked out locally. I do git stash (because I am not interested in keeping the changes made locally), and then git pull to pull in all the changes made to branch A. Then I want to switch to working on branch B. I git checkout branch B. Now suddenly, I am seeing the changes made to branch A *after* branch B was created, *in* my local branch B repo. How is this possible?

As a sanity test, I checked out master, and lo and behold, the additions to branch A were present in master.

Shouldn't checking out a branch *only* show what is in the branch, regardless of what was on the local repo before the new branch was checked out? We have to either commit or stash any changes before we checkout a new branch, so it's not like this is a safety measure to save work that may not have been saved. Is this git behavior normal, or do I need to fix my git settings?

Comment: When you create a branch, there is no automatic action taking place if the _upstream_ is somehow modified... you normally need to either rebase on top of the upstream branch or merge the upstream so you get those changes.

Comment: Ok... as long as you have _uncommitted changes_ in your working tree, they are not considered to belong to any branch.... if you are on branch `A` and have modified 2 files (you have not committed those changes to the branch) and you ask to checkout `B`, those changes will go along with you when you checkout (it's actually not that simple, there are some checks performed to allow that to happen if there are changes in your working tree)... that will stop happening when you commit those changes.

Comment: You are absolutely correct. There was an untracked, uncommited file I had added that I missed that got carried through the branches. Thank you for your suggestion!